# Laravel CRUD search function

Tags: laravel, search, filter, routes, crud

I need your help that how can i make a search function for my laravel crud system?
I would like to make a search function where admins can search about users name and it works like a filter and after the search only shown the users that equals with the search.

admin.users.index (Blade file):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form action="/search" method="GET">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Keresés</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
    

    <div class="card">

    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Profilkép</th>
      <th scope="col">Név</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Telefonszám</th>
      <th scope="col">Műveletek</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      @foreach($users as $user)
      <tr>
      <th scope="row"><img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" style=" width:32x; height:32px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;"></th>
      <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
      <td>{{ $user->phone }}</td>
      
      <td>

      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href=" {{ route('admin.users.edit', $user->id) }}" role="button">Szerkesztés</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('delete-user-form-{{ $user->id }}').submit()">
            Törlés
      </button>
        <form id="delete-user-form-{{ $user->id }}" action="{{ route('admin.users.destroy', $user->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        @csrf
        @method("DELETE")
    </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
      @endforeach
      
  </tbody>
</table>
{{ $users->links() }}
    </div>
```

UserController Search function:

```
   public function index(Request $request)
    {


        if(Gate::denies('logged-in')){
            dd('no acces');
        }
        if(Gate::allows('is-admin')){
            return view('admin.users.index', ['users' => User::paginate(10)]);
        }
        dd("adminnak kell lenned");
        $users = User::paginate(10);

        return view('admin.users.index')
                    ->with([
                        'users' => $users
                    ]);
    }

    public function search(Request $request) {
        
        $search = $request->get('search');
        $users = User::table('users')->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(10);
        return view('admin', ['users' => $users]);
    }
```

And i dont have route in web.php because i dont know how can i solve this. :(
Please help me!
thank you for your reply!

Comment: To add a route : read the docs, thats easy. But you don't need to. You can use the index action with a query parameter 'search'

Comment: Can you help me how to implement this in code?

Comment: I will not write the code for you, but wil help you get started: Change your form action to the index route, read the query param with `$request->query('search')` . Now you only have to make an if statement on the query param with the where like statement (in your index action)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.table').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "scrollY": 850,
        "scrollX": true,
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": -1,
            "orderable": false,
        },
        ],
        "ordering": false,
    });
```

Put this command to javascript.

add this css

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
```

add this js

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

this is datatable search without anything. if you want use this method.

Comment: Thats not the question. The question is about searching using the controller, not client side. Side note, when you've got a big dataset, DataTables fail.

Comment: Then you need to send request and trigger your table

Comment: I know, But the real question is, why import jQuery and DataTables, to replace 1 simple where statement?  Apart from that most developers are walking away from jQuery, because vanilla JS can basically do the same. This is overkill for the functionality that is required in the question.